# Socket max fds reached

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

On server side Sockets fds are reaching to max limit, is there any configuration in linux system level that can be set for TCP ipv4 where system(kernel) takes care of closing the idle/ unused socket fds, so that socket fds doesn't reach fd max.

Comment: The kernel has no way of knowing which sockets are idle/unused; your app will need to include logic to call `close()` on sockets when it wants to close them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way for the system to know that an idle socket won't be reused or closed by the application. You need to fix whatever bug is causing your application to leak sockets.

Comment: Why is there no way? Is it related with the layered design principles?

Comment: It's for the same reason I can't know that my boss won't call me tomorrow. The OS has no way to know what the application will do in the future. If it releases the resources, the identifier is reused, and the application tries to use the identifier to access the old resource, *boom*.